# How to remove a specific version of a file in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I need to remove a specific version of a versioned file in my repo, but I do not know how to do it.

I can view the file using hg cat --rev [version] [file-name], but I do not know to remove it.

Anyone know how to remove a specific file version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**: If your repo is public, it's very hard. If it's private, easier.

---

**Long answer**: Mercurial, being a changeset-oriented CVS, does not actually store file revisions. Instead, it stores changes between revisions (diffs).

In addition to that, every changeset id is calculated as a cryptographic hash based on the content of the revision. This means that if you altered a single changeset, every descendant changeset of it would be changed. This is the price of rewriting history in Mercurial.

### Private repo

If the changeset you need to change was not pushed anywhere (or the repo itself is private), then you can alter history as you like.

- If the changeset is a recent one, consider using [Mercurial Queues](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension): you can import the changesets into the queue, go to the changeset in question, undo the change to one particular file, then reapply the rest of the queue.
- If the changeset was committed a long time ago, you might probably update to its parent, [graft](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#graft) the offending changeset (you'll probably have to stick in a dummy changeset to make it work), import it to MQ, modify it, then `rebase --detach` the rest of the ancestors on top of it.

### Public repo

You can do the same with the private repo, but remember the copy of the lineage will be created:

```
-- 1 -- 2 -- A -- B -- C -- D    original A and its descendants
         \
          A' -- B' -- C' -- D'   modified A' and its descendants
```

Even after you replace `A`–`D` with `A'`–`D'`, everyone who pulled from your repo will still have `A`–`D`! You'll have to find a way to make them strip this lineage.

Comment: “then graft the rest of the ancestors on top of it.” – you mean rebase the descendants, right? This should preserve merges among descendants, too...

Comment: Also a mechanism called ‘obsolete markers’ is being worked on, with which you will be able to propagate the stripping of A-D.

Comment: @LaurensHolst: Correct me is I'm mistaken. Rebasing `B` on top of `A'` will create a new changeset `B'` with _two_ parents: `A'` and `A`. Rebase is just a fast-forward merge.

Comment: @LaurensHolst: Turns out I never noticed this option. The cryptic help text for it doesn't help, either. Thanks for the heads up! I've updated my post.

Comment: Also, I think you could use the new `commit --amend` on the grafted changeset instead of MQ.